# VS Code, Windows, OneDrive, GoLive issues

Tags: visual-studio-code, synchronization, onedrive

Hello, I am new to VS Code, used Atom before. We were trying to use "GoLive" to view some html with javascript, and getting strange errors. It seemed like the errors had to do with the fact that files were being served from the user's OneDrive at some point, instead of from their hard drive, where we'd put them originally. I assume the solution is to un-sync the folder we're working and testing in from OneDrive?

Other folders (and projects) were working, so we tried renaming some folders in the VS Code Explorer, and at that point, we were not allowed to do so.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Unsynced oneDrive and restarted, and that fixed the problem.